# python "run module" results in error

Tags: python

I'm a beginner on Python and here is my test code

```
def main():
Test1()
Test2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()

class Test1:

def __init__(self):
    print("test1");

class Test2:

def __init__(self):
    print("test2");
```

And when I try "Run Module", I get

> NameError: name 'Test1' is not defined

How am I supposed to run the main method?

Comment: Your `if __name__ == '__main__'` should generally be at the end of your file, after you've declared classes and functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the definition of Test1 and Test2 before main function.

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self):
        print("test1")

class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
        print("test2")

def main():
    Test1()
    Test2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

OR

Move the "if __name__ == "__main__":" block after the definition of Test1 and Test2 classes.

```
def main():
    Test1()
    Test2()

class Test1:
    def __init__(self):
        print("test1")

class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
        print("test2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It should be a similar issue with the incomplete definition in C programming language. When you execute the code inside "if __name__ == "__main__":", it call the function main(). And inside the main() function, you are going to create two objects as Test1() and Test2(). But from the beginning of the file to the "if __name__ == "__main__":" block, there is no definition of these two classes as Test1() and Test2().

Answer (score 1):

you need to move main on the bottom of the file. also you dont have to use `;`

```
# python doesn't "know" what Test1 is at this point
class Test1:
    def __init__(self):
        print("test1")

# At this point python "knows" what is Test1 and you can use it
class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
        print("test2")

# Thats why main goes in the end of the file always
# Because here python is aware of Test1 and Test2
def main():
    Test1()
    Test2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```